# Grub command not allowing to boot

Tags: boot, laptop, grub

Installed redhat linux server and windows 7 as dual boot. While adjusting storage space on my laptop on windows, I deleted redhat Linux partition.

Now I rebooted my laptop. It's always showing GRUB command prompt. Cannot boot to windows. Computer gets shutdown very soon once GRUB command prompted for a while.

My data there on windows only. How to boot to windows? Tried with windows media. Computer abruptly gets shutdown during loading files from windows cd. Tried for 30 times. Same experience.

Any inputs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grub overwrites the bootsector of the HDD to be the first program the BIOS sees. You can revert it back to windows by following the steps to get to the command prompt as in [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392). Basically, you boot from the windows media and choose repair and then get a command prompt. Here issuing the command 
`bootrec /FixMbr` will write a standard windows bootloader to the HDD and grub will be removed. Reboot and set the HDD as your boot device